# Как посчитать количество открытий PDF-файла (как ссылки)

Tags: php, html, ссылка

У меня есть две ссылки:
Одна (например):
"/php/start.php"
Другая:
"/files/file.pdf"
Требуется статистика по использованию этих ссылок.
Когда я нажимаю на первую ссылку, я имею возможность в файле start.php зафиксировать
это нажатие (типа: колич = колич++), а уже потом в этом же модуле делать то, что требуется.

```
Во втором же случае сразу открывается pdf-файл и возможности увеличить счётчик нет.
```

Вопрос дилетанта:
Как это сделать и можно ли это сделать средствами html + php ?

Comment: Во втором случае: открыть текстовый log-файл веб-сервера и посчитать за сутки?

Answer (score 0):

`php` - обрабатывается веб-сервером при обращении к нему, поэтому счетчик обновляется, а вот статичные файлы, будь то картинки, музыка и другие документы не обрабатываются на сервере, а просто отдаются напрямую пользователю. Не зря они называются статичные файлы.

Логичным было бы решение, включить логирование запросов, если они еще не были включены, и собирать статистику обращений из файла `access.log`.

Менее логичным и более сложным - сделать единую точку входа, и все запросы к веб-серверу перенаправлять и обрабатывать через, например, `index.php`, что вызовет дополнительный расход памяти и снизит эффективность работы веб-сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Andrey Mihalev, второй способ для меня совсем непонятен.
А вот через access.log вполне симпатичный способ.
Сейчас просматриваю этот файл.
Спасибо, Andrey Mihalev, Спасибо, Daemon.
Нашёл ещё один способ, но он слегка ущербный.
Через дублирование ссылки в файле PHP
Ущербность в том, что если нажата первая ссылка, не факт, что будет нажата вторая.
Всё-таки возьму на вооружение access.log
Спасибо